# WebGL texture rendering partially

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

I am facing a *very* obscure issue.

I am loading .obj 3d models into a WebGL application I am working on. I am parsing them using a custom function. I know it works correctly. Because I get this:

[image: Wood textured cube]

Granted the texture is stretched way too much. But that's the way the UVs are mapped.

But, when I load a goose model here's what I get:

[image: Goose no texture]

An untextured goose. I am using the same texture.

Weirder still is the fact that the texture renders only around the eyes. If I don't draw the wireframe, I get this:

[image: Goose eyes]

Those two tiny specs that I've circled are the eyes.

Just to make sure that it wasn't this model, I tried another one:

[image: Partially texture axe]

**I have no idea why it won't render the texture everywhere else.**

Here's what I've tried:

- Recalcuated normals and exported from Blender again. Same outcome.
- Loaded models in Photoshop and they preview correctly. Meaning models are fine.
- Checked my parsing of the .obj file into a usable format for WebGL over and over. Also, since the cube loads correctly, I assume it's not that.
- Tried switching off MipMapping, disabling CULL_FACE and changing winding order. No difference.
- Used different texture image. The texture images are all NPOT. Tried non NPOT. Nothing changed, except with different images the texels of the little eyes or the fragment on the axe changed to the texture.
- Checked UV mappings, all look fine. No negative or out of range values.

I am totally out of ideas. If someone has had similar experiences, I'd appreciate pointers as to where to look next.

I generally don't like to ask questions without posting the code, but the code is very convoluted because I'm using sweet.js for custom javascript syntax. Let me know if anyone would like to look at the code and I could try and clean up some code and upload somewhere.

Comment: A long shot : are the polygons filled the first polygons of the model ?

Comment: @GameAlchemist Yes! That was it! I had a hard coded value for the number of faces to draw using DrawElements. Thank you so very very much. I just changed it to vertices/3 and it works like a charm. Please post your comment as an answer. I want to give you so very many points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your images i was wondering if you did not draw a constant number of polygon, or if the draw started then silently failed on its road because of some bug. That's why i asked if the drawn polygons were the first of the models.
And so it seems that indeed there was a hard coded limit to the number of drawn polygons.
Glad you found it !